# Firefox inspect addon's network traffic

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition `60.0b6` on Mac OS X. I'm inspecting an addon (XPI file) developed by someone else with WebExtensions API.

How can I inspect the network traffic from the addon (XHR traffic in particular)? For normal web pages, I can simply open the developer console, but there is no such console for addons (even though addons are just javascripts).

Answer (score 5):

You can enable add-on debugging by visiting `about:debugging`, and then click `Debug` for your extension to access the console and inspect network traffic. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging for more information)